# Stuck in ">", after mistyping command?

Tags: git, mingw

`git commit -a -m "globgolab`
I didn't add a " at the end, pressed enter, and got stuck in > hell. What to do?
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxd5f.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you didn't add a `"` at the end and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `bash` decided the command was not completed so it issued a secondary prompt (`>`) to allow to complete the command. You can do one of two things:

Type `"` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to complete the command and finish committing.

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt committing and return to the command prompt. Don't forget to commit later.

Comment: @ikanai: you need a good book or tutorial on doing bash programming. (Bash has a full programming language in it!) The `>` prompt is from variable `PS2`; `PS1` is your normal command-line prompt and there are more prompts `PS3` and `PS4`. These are described (minimally) in [the bash manual pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html); there's a [reference doc](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) as well, though it's not really a tutorial.

Comment: What do you think bash could come handy in? I want to do webdev mostly, and lean towards freelance as far as working goes. I thought git could come in handy since I will use it, along with github, so I set out to read the first 3 chapter up until server git. That's what I got recommended.